# JIRA - Link issues and subtasks

Tags: jira

I have imported 2 excel files to JIRA, one excel contains only issues, and another contains only subtasks.

Both excels have a ID field.

Is there a way to link issues and subtasks with the same ID?

Thanks

Comment: I recently imported a project plan with subtasks from Excel into Jira. The Issue ID and Parent ID are required in the same sheet in Excel because that's how the Jira import creates the relationship from task to subtask. I did this recently and wrote a blog about my experiences which may help. See https://blog.aptitive.com/importing-a-project-plan-with-subtasks-from-excel-into-jira-25ae852008e6

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you do a single import. Give each parent a unique value in the Issue Id column. Then give each subtask the appropriate value in the Parent Id column.